# How to get standalone5G network type in iOS

Tags: swift, 5g, network-framework

In my project, i need to get which 5G network is connected.
e.g. standalone5G,dualConnectivity5G(_:)

I am able to get Interfacetype by

```
if let networktype = NetworkReachability.shared.interfaceType
{
    switch networktype
    {
    case .cellular:
        print("mobiledata Newtwork")
    case .wifi:
        print("wifi Newtwork")
    case .wiredEthernet:
        print("LAN Newtwork")
    default:
        print("Other Newtwork")
    }
}
```

But Get Following error while

[image]

```
if let networktype = NWInterface.RadioType.Cellular
{
    switch networktype
    {
    case .standalone5G(<#T##Network.NWInterface.RadioType.Cellular.NewRadio5GVariant#>):
        print("CDMA Network")
        default:
        print("Other")
    }
}
```